# UISplitViewController: Navigationbar for master view hidden after rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I have two navigationBars, one for my master view and one for my detail view.

I created my `UISplitviewController` in the interface builder and attached a navigation controller as master and detail view and linked the actual views. The detail view always shows a working navigation bar, the master view only when the iPad hasn't rotated since app start and is in landscape mode.
I've double-checked the source-code of my storyboard, but the master and the detail navigationcontroller are the same except for the IDs and x/y:

```
<!--Navigation Controller-->
<scene sceneID="dm7-tD-dAR">
    <objects>
        <navigationController id="1xf-lO-tOw" sceneMemberID="viewController">
            <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
            <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" translucent="NO" id="rQ3-i9-XSv">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            </navigationBar>
            <connections>
                <segue destination="VeO-5d-klv" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="gtO-mE-rZu"/>
            </connections>
        </navigationController>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="tEm-wf-PLl" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
    </objects>
    <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1201.5" y="-343"/>
</scene>
```

I've tried changing the canvasLocation to no use. Both detail and master view are inheriting from the same `BasicViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following method in my code (coming from a legacy project I built on):

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

This is quite obvious the cause. It's interesting though that this method doesn't get called when the view appears in landscape - that's not what I expected from the name.